# WSO2 clustering in a distributed deployment

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to understand clustering concept of WSO2. My basic understanding of cluster is that there are 2 or more server with same function using VIP or load balance in front. So I would like to know which of the WSO2 components can be clustered. I am trying to achieve configuration mentioned in this diagram.

Image of Config I am trying to achieve:

[image: Image of Config I am trying to achieve]

Can this configuration is achievable or not?

Can we cluster 2 Publisher nodes and 2 store nodes or not?

And how do we cluster Key Manager use same setting as Identity Manager?

Should we use port offset when running 2 components on the same server? And if yes how we make sure that components are using the ports as mentioned in port offset?

Should we create separate external database for each CarnonDB datasource entry in master_datasource.xml file or we can keep using local H2 database for this. I have created following databases Let me know if I am correct in doing this or not. wso2 databases I created:

[image: wso2 databases I created]

I made several copies of wso2 binary files as shown in Image and copied them to the servers where I want to run 2 components on same server. Is this correct way of running 2 components on same server?

For Load balancing which components should we load balance and what ports should be use for load balancing?

Answer (score 2):

1. That configuration is achievable. But Analytics servers are best to run on separate servers as they utilize a lot of resources.
2. Yes, you can.
3. Yes, you need port-offset. If you're on Linux, you can use `netstat -pln` command and filter by server PID.
4. Every server needs a local database and other databases are shared as mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0
5. Having copies is one way of doing that. Another way is letting a single server act as multiple components. For example, you can run publisher and store components together. You can see the recommended patterns in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Deployment+Patterns.
6. Except for Traffic manager, you can load balance every other component. For traffic manager, you can use fail-over. Here are the ports you need to load balance.

   ```
   Servlet port - 9443(https)/9763 (For admin console and admin services)
   NIO port - 8243(https)/8280 (For API calls at gateway)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there documentation I can follow to cluster 2 Publisher Nodes and 2 Store nodes and also 2 Key Manager Nodes? I can't seem to find the documentation for these.